# Remove debugger line from script

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, webpack

Most of the developers write "debugger" in typescript to debug code on browser.

```
debugger;
this.colId = params.column.colId;
this.optionValue = params.optionCompose;
this.selectedText = params.value;
```

I am working with angular 4 and uses webpack module bundler to bundle my files. Problem here is at the time of bundle creation we are unable to remove debugger line from code. Do we have any provision or work around?

Answer (score 1):

Use [string-replace-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin)

```
var StringReplacePlugin = require("string-replace-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
   module: {
      loaders: [
         { 
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
                replacements: [
                    {
                        pattern: /(debugger[;]?)/ig,
                        replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                ]})
            }
      ]
   },
   plugins: [
      new StringReplacePlugin()
   ]
}
```

This must replace by emptiness all occurrences of the `debugger;` in all *ts* files.